# Is it safe to use removeObject: during enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, foundation

This code runs without crashing and I don't see anything in the documentation, but is it really safe?

```
[mutableArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    // do some stuff to obj before removing it
    [mutableArray removeObject:obj];
}];
```

Comment: Some useful answers here: [Collection was mutated while being enumerated error in objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457369/collection-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated-error-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this **should not be done**.

As in enumeration the object is treated as const.

I tried same code, I received following error:

```
Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x10053b8d0> was mutated while being enumerated.
```

The Code:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray=[NSMutableArray new];
[mutableArray addObject:@"A"];
[mutableArray addObject:@"Ab"];
[mutableArray addObject:@"Ac"];
[mutableArray addObject:@"Ad"];

[mutableArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    // do some stuff to obj before removing it
    [mutableArray removeObject:obj];
    NSLog(@"--->%@",mutableArray);
}];
```

Comment: Even after posting this answer, i am wondering in the error it says `NSArrayM is mutatated` it is `M` not `I`. so why cant a mutableArray be mutated.

Comment: Because collections must not be mutated during enumeration (see answers to "duplicate question"). It does not matter if the collection is mutable or not.

Answer (score 5):

This is something you should never do. Instead, collect all the element indexes into an `NSMutableIndexSet` object and then later use the `removeObjectsAtIndexes:` to remove all of the objects at once.