# How to load large data from NSFetchResultController in background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I am using `NSFetchResultController` to show data in `UICollectionView` from Core data. `UICollectionViewCell` contain table view in it. so in short there is very large amount of data showing in that `UITableView`. I am showing `NSFetchResultController` to show data in that table views too. 
Now the problem is when i scroll `UICollectionView` it loads data from database to show in `UITableView`. as the amount of data is large so scrolling of `UICollectionView` is very choppy. Any help
i though that i should move the fetch request to background thread but it start crashing app and giving expection

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSSetM: 0x15722f80> was mutated while being enumerated.'
```

Comment: I'd suggest from your current description you have a number of issues to address. Am I correct in understanding that you have a `UITableView` embedded in each collection view? If that is the case, I'd recommend you control the amount of data your FRC fetches for each table view, perhaps double that which can be displayed in the table view space? Then work on installing a trigger for each collection view that when tapped / selected, performs another fetch for all the data for that table view. Also I recommend you read about how to perform efficient fetches - Core Data, 2nd Ed by Marcus S Zarra

Comment: And your error is related to the fact that you cannot mutate / change an `NSMutableSet` during enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

I think @andrew is right, The problem is in your array make sure that your array or whatever datalist control you used for this is must be mutable, just mutable this it will solve your issue.

see below answer like same question as you ask.

[Collection was mutated while being enumerated error in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457369/collection-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated-error-in-objective-c)