# Why is NSFastEnumeration fast?

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocoa, iterator, fast-enumeration

Does anybody know whether [`NSFastEnumeration`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSFastEnumeration_protocol/Reference/NSFastEnumeration.html) is really faster (as in run-time performance) than using [`NSEnumerator`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSEnumerator_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or (for arrays) using an integer counter and loop through the elements?

If it is indeed faster, how does it achieve that speed?

Or perhaps the "fast" actually refers to faster in *writing* the iteration code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the first answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163169/fast-enumeration-vs-nsenumerator-in-objective-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the container, `NSFastEnumeration` is at least as fast as `NSEnumerator` but usually much faster since it involves fewer method calls.

Instead of having to call `nextObject` for every item in the array, with `NSFastEnumerator` the array can give back a block of objects in a C array at once. Iterating that C array is *way* faster than having to do lots of method calls, which each look up and return just one object.

Answer (score 5):

`Fast enumeration` is not faster than any "for" loop. In a general sense, that is impossible because basic loops are already as optimized as they can be.

Instead, `fast enumeration` is faster than a "for" or "while" loop that fetches data on every iteration from an Objective-C object using an Objective-C method call.

It does this by fetching the data in batches, reducing the overhead of calling a method on each iteration. Removing the method call from the inner part of the loop also has compiler optimisation benefits.