# How for in loop works internally - Objective C - Foundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, foundation, for-in-loop, fast-enumeration

I found this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163334/1364174

Which presents how `for in` loop is implemented.

```
NSFastEnumerationState __enumState = {0};
id __objects[MAX_STACKBUFF_SIZE];
NSUInteger __count;
while ((__count = [myArray countByEnumeratingWithState:&__enumState objects:__objects count:MAX_STACKBUFF_SIZE]) > 0) {
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < __count; i++) {
        id obj = __objects[i];
        [obj doSomething];
    }
}
```

The problem is that,  I found it wrong.

First of all, when you have Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) turned on, you got an error

`Sending '__strong id *' to parameter of type '__unsafe_unretained_id*' changes retain/release properties of pointer`

[image: Screenshot of an error]

But even when I turn ARC off I found out that I __object array seems to behave strangely :

[image: Screenshot of error2]

This is actual Code (I assumed MAX_STACKBUFF_SIZE to be 40):

```
@autoreleasepool {

        NSArray *myArray = @[@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f", @"g"];
        int MAX_STACKBUFF_SIZE = 40;
        NSFastEnumerationState __enumState = {0};
        id __objects[MAX_STACKBUFF_SIZE];
        NSUInteger __count;
        while ((__count = [myArray countByEnumeratingWithState:&__enumState objects:__objects count:MAX_STACKBUFF_SIZE]) > 0) {
            for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < __count; i++) {
                id obj = __objects[i];
                __enumState.itemsPtr
                NSLog(@" Object from __objects ! %@", obj);  // on screenshot different message

            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
```

I got EXC_BAD_ACESS when I try to get the contents of the __object array.
I also found out that when you try to iterate through __enumState.itemsPtr  it actually works.

Could you explain me what is going on here ? Why my `__objects` seems to be "shrunken down". And why it doesn't contains desired object? And why is that error when ARC is turned on.

Thank you very very much in advance for your time and effort!  (I provided screenshot for better understanding what causes an error)

Comment: I don't get it, why not just use `for in ___`?

Comment: @0x7fffffff  I try to understand the implementation of `for in` loop.

Comment: @bluesm Don't take the code in that answer literally. It's pseudocode *at best.* It is almost surely not how the creators of the compiler implemented the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, strong pointers cannot be used in C-structures, as explained in the "Transitioning to ARC Release Notes", therefore the objects array has be be declared
as

```
__unsafe_unretained  id __objects[MAX_STACKBUFF_SIZE];
```

if you compile with ARC.

Now it is not obvious (to me) from the `NSFastEnumeration` documentation, but it is
explained in [Cocoa With Love:Implementing countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/05/implementing-countbyenumeratingwithstat.html)
that the implementation need not fill the supplied objects array, but can just set
`__enumState.itemsPtr` to an existing array (e.g. some internal storage). In that case, the contents of the
`__objects` array is undefined, which causes the crash.

Replacing

```
id obj = __objects[i];
```

by

```
id obj = __enumState.itemsPtr[i];
```

gives the expected result, which is what you observed.

Another reference can be found in the ["FastEnumerationSample"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/FastEnumerationSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009411) sample code:

> You have two choices when implementing this method:
>
> 1) Use the stack
>   based array provided by stackbuf. If you do this, then you must
>   respect the value of 'len'.
>
> 2) Return your own array of objects. If
>   you do this, return the full length of the array returned until you
>   run out of objects, then return 0. For example, a linked-array
>   implementation may return each array in order until you iterate
>   through all arrays.
>
> In either case, `state->itemsPtr` MUST be a valid
>   array (non-nil). ...